# How to use fast-filter with react-virtualized-select

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-select

I would love to use react-virtualized-select with bvaughn's react-select-fast-filter-options.  I have referred to the example here [fastfilteroptions](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-select-fast-filter-options)

Relevant code:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import createFilterOptions from 'react-select-fast-filter-options';


export const getIndexedOptions = createSelector(
    state => state.companyreducer.options,
    options => createFilterOptions({options})
    )
```

On debugging I can see that the redux store is accessed and the options array loaded.

Now for the select component

```
 class renderTypeahead extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            companies: [],
            selectedCompany: ''
        }

    }
    onInputChange(value) {
        this.props.fetchData(value);
    }

    onChange(event) {
        console.log(event);


        if (this.props.input.onChange && event != null) {

            this.props.input.onChange(event.CompanyDescription);

        } 
    }


    render() {

    const { selectedCompany } = this.state;
    const { options, companies } = this.props;

    return(
        <Select


        labelKey='CompanyDescription'

        filterOptions = {options.filterOptions}
        onBlur = {() => this.props.input.onBlur(this.props.input.value) }
        onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
        onInputChange={(value) => this.onInputChange(value)}
        options={companies}value={this.props.input.value}
        valueKey='CompanyID'/>
        )
    }
}

        function mapStateToProps(storeState) {

            return { 
                companies: storeState.companyreducer.options,
                options: getIndexedOptions(storeState)

            }
        }

        function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
            return {

                fetchData: (inputChars) => dispatch(fetchCompanyOptions(inputChars))
            }
        }
```

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(renderTypeahead)
When I run this and click the drop down arrow I can see the company list however on typing to search I get no results found.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your full code? Especially I want to see `onChange` function, since it is the one that is not working.

Comment: Thank you Deividas, for your time. I have edited the original post and added the full code as requested.